# ExpandableListView inside ExpandableListView getting proper ID

Tags: android, json, native, expandablelistview

I have app that reads JSON from assets to 3 arrays. Next those arrays are my parents and childs in ExpandableListView. Parent in first ExpandableListView is TextView, and Child is second ExpandableListView. I created two Adapters for each listview, but wrong childs are showed when i click on each main parent.

```
public class MainParentAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    Context context;
    String[] MainparentList;
    String[] MainchildList;
    String[] child2;
    AssetManager assets;
    SecondAdapter sa;
    CustomList cust;
    public MainParentAdapter(Context context, AssetManager assets) throws IOException, JSONException {
        this.context=context;
        this.assets=assets;
        ParseJSON();
        cust=new CustomList(context);
        cust.setAdapter(sa);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return MainparentList.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView tv=new TextView(context);
        tv.setText(MainparentList[groupPosition]+"  "+MainchildList[groupPosition]+"   "+child2[groupPosition]);
        tv.setTextSize(30);
        return tv;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        cust=new CustomList(context);
        cust.setAdapter(sa);
        cust.setGroupIndicator(null);
        return cust;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
    public String loadJSON() {
        String json = null;
        try {
            InputStream is = assets.open("test.json");
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;
    }
    public void ParseJSON() throws JSONException {
        JSONArray JA=new JSONArray(loadJSON());
        JSONObject jo=null;
        MainparentList=new String[JA.length()];
        MainchildList=new String[JA.length()];
        child2=new String[JA.length()];
        sa=new SecondAdapter(context);
        for (int i=0;i<MainparentList.length;i++) {
            jo = JA.getJSONObject(i);
            MainparentList[i] = jo.getString("name");
            MainchildList[i] = jo.getString("species");
            child2[i] = jo.getString("id");
        }
        sa.SecondParent=MainchildList;
        sa.SecondChild=child2;
    }
}
```

In this Main parent I am creating each child by custom ExpandableListView. In ParseJSON function i get all values of objects in JSON, and copy the arrays to the second adapter, to read them there.

And there is second Adapter:

```
public class SecondAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
{
    Context context;
    String[] SecondParent;
    String[]SecondChild;
    boolean dip=false,dip2=false;

    public SecondAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context=context;

    }
    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return groupPosition;
    }
    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
            TextView tv = new TextView(context);
            tv.setText(SecondChild[groupPosition]);
            tv.setPadding(150, 5, 5, 5);
            tv.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            return tv;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition)
    {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition)
    {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        TextView tv = new TextView(context);
        tv.setText(SecondParent[groupPosition]);
        tv.setPadding(50, 7, 7, 7);
        return tv;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

}
```

Whren It displays, only shows first ExpandableListView right. Each child of parent have the same values as the first one. I want to have proper values for parent, as it is written in JSON file:

```
 [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "species": "Capra hircus",
    "name": "Goat"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "species": "Panthera pardus",
    "name": "Leopard"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "species": "Equus zebra",
    "name": "Zebra"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "species": "Equus swinia",
    "name": "Swinia"
  }
]
```

For each name should be displayed species and then child of species is id. But all of the elements (name) have the same child.

[image]

So how can I get proper child for parents in second list?

Thanks.